# Delete row table intercepting the button?

Tags: javascript, row

I have a table in which you can add new rows but also to remove. I used an outdated system, I pressed a button and insert the row to be deleted, but this is not the best.

Now I create for each row created a button that says 'delete', I would make sure that every time this button is pressed, the corresponding row is deleted. 
Can you do that?

```
input5.onclick = function Ultimo(event)
                {
                    event = event || window.event;             
                    var row =  event.target || event.srcElement;
                    document.getElementById('table').deleteRow(row);
                    cont--;
                }
```

the button is generated every time you press '+' in my form. 
For each button septum its onclick, with the function concerned with the removal of the rows. 
Cont is a line counter.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple if all you want to do is remove it from the DOM.  You could do it in pure Javascript or with JQuery. It would be more readable and maintainable using JQuery.

**Pure Javascript Solution:**

http://jsfiddle.net/k5mfe/

```
<table>
    <tr><td>One</td><td><a href="#" onclick="removeRow(this)">Delete</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Two</td><td><a href="#" onclick="removeRow(this)">Delete</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Three</td><td><a href="#" onclick="removeRow(this)">Delete</a></td></tr>
</table>


<script>
    function removeRow(el)
{
    var tr = el.parentElement.parentElement;
    tr.parentElement.removeChild(tr);

}
</script>
```

**JQuery Solution**

http://jsfiddle.net/k5mfe/1/

```
<script>
function removeRow(el)
{
    $(el).parents('tr').remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: i changed in:

input5.onclick = function Ultimo(event)
{var tr = event.parentElement.parentElement;
                        tr.parentElement.removeChild(tr);
     }

but when i clicked on delete button, all row have been deleted :(

Comment: Delete the event parameter from Ultimo and replace "event" with input5 then it will work (assuming that that input5 is your button).

Comment: i obtain this error:

cannot read property 'parentelement' of undefined

Comment: Basically, the idea is to walk the DOM and find the row.  Then, on the row you get the parent (which should be a table or tbody).  Then from the table or tbody you can delete the row. You should get out the debugger to help you troubleshoot what's wrong.